# Tenda AC9 - Current Time: 1999-12-31 18:31:13 (unsynchronized with internet time)

Tags: router, scheduled-tasks, time

I have a Tenda AC9 (AC1200) and I can not change the date that appear on time settings and I do not have any manual changes or automatic internet one to synchronize, so this problem started 1 day ago and it appears like in title.

I reset and reboot the router and reconnect to internet service provider several time, changed the time table and the issue is still there!

So I have problems with **WiFi Schedule** - the schedule takes effect only if the system time is synchronized with the internet time and - **Automatic maintenance** takes effect only if the system time is synchronized with the internet time.

Any idea to solve this strange problem?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Log into the router at 192.168.0.1, Advanced Link, Tools, Time:   Does this work set internet time?

Comment: As I mentioned in the post, no, i have no settings on time in the router like in the pic...

Comment: Maybe do a complete hardware reset and set the router up again.

Comment: As i mentioned above i did this severels times :)

Comment: Maybe time to try a different router.  It the basic Tenda cannot manage time, that would be a hardware or firmware issue.

Comment: soft reset, hard reset, rebot, reconfiegure from scratch, nothing the time is not moving to date!

Comment: Replace it as noted.

Comment: Since there were many “me too” answers, I guess the firmware is configured to use an NTP server that is currently not available. Since the setting does not appear to be user-configurable, there is nothing you can do.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem last week and it probably affected many other owners of Tenda routers but most of them didn't notice because they do not use time-based features like WiFi schedule or automatic maintenance.

I solved it using the Backup/Restore functionality (it can be found under the "System Settings" menu) as described below:

1. Backup the router configuration. It produces the configuration as a downloadable file named `RouterCfm.cfg` that your browser downloads.
2. **Very important!** Make a copy of file `RouterCfm.cfg` and keep it safe. If something goes wrong, it could be used to restore the router in its current state.
3. Open the file `RouterCfm.cfg` in a plain text editor. Do not use a text editor that formats the text, like MS Word or OpenOffice Writer! Use vi or Notepad or other editor you usually use for plain text.
4. Find the line:

   ```
   sys.timentpserver=time.windows.com
   ```

   Replace `time.windows.com` with a different time server. For example:

   ```
   sys.timentpserver=pool.ntp.org
   ```

   Check the site https://www.ntppool.org/en/ to learn about NTP (it is the time-synchronization protocol.)
5. Save the file and load it using the Restore functionality of the router.
   The router will restart (this takes about one minute).
6. Wait 5-10 minutes then check the date & time of the router. It should display the correct date and time. Be patient. It does not synchronize its date&time as soon as it restarts but several minutes later.

If something goes wrong, use the backup copy of `RouterCfm.cfg` that you created on step 2 to restore the router to the start state.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Tenda AC9 manual that I found, the Time & Date page (manual page 108) is only for setting the time zone.

[image]

The router should automatically get its time from NTP. However, the manual does not describe a way to manually configure NTP server(s). The router might have a preconfigured NTP server, but it seems to fail to connect to it.

If there are newer firmware versions available for your router, I recommend you update it.